# MadCap Flare: Cannot import project from a TFS repository

Tags: tfs, tfvc, madcap

I am trying to connect MadCap Flare with our TFS repository.

I have the whole project check in the TFS Server, but when I try to import the project from the "Source Control Explorer" in MadCap Flare

[image]

I get this error:

> Local workspace detected - MadCap Flare only supports server
>   workspaces.  Please contact your system administrator to help resolve
>   the issue.

After that, I created a server workspace through Visual Studio but I still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the project on your local disk to another folder temporarily. Then import the project via Flare to a new empty folder on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The change you need to make is actually in Visual Studio. In the workspace settings under advanced there is a setting that allows for local or server workspace. You want to make sure you are using server and public.